# How to avoid empty page in an align environment

Tags: align

I have the following long code:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[fixamsmath,disallowspaces]{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\underline{Verwendete Bezeichnungen}

\begin{align*}
\sigma_ {Ab} &: \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
Koeffizient f{\"u}r die Berechnung der Temperaturabnahme des Warmwasserspeichers \\
 durch den Verbrauch von Warmwasser \end{tabular} \\
\sigma_{Ver} &:  \text{Temperaturverlust des Warmwasserspeichers}  \\
\sigma_ {Zu} &: \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
Koeffizient f{\"u}r die Berechnung der Temperaturzunahme des Warmwasserspeichers \\
 durch das Verbrennen von Gas \end{tabular} \\
d_j &: \text{sp{\"a}testm{\"o}glicher Zeitpunkt an dem das Programm von Ger{\"a}t $j$ beendet sein muss}\\
g_{j,Run,l}^{a} (t_r) &: \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
Gasverbrauch des Ger{\"a}tes $j$ in der Phase $l$ unter Verwendung von Profil $a$.\\
Gasverbrauch ist relativ zum Startzeitpunkt angegeben \end{tabular} \\
G_{Ges}(t) &: \text{gesamter Gasverbrauch aller Gasverbraucher in Bezug auf die Systemzeit $t$}\\
G^{GV}_j(t)&: \text{Gasverbrauch des Ger{\"a}tes $j$ in Bezug auf die Systemzeit $t$ }\\
J_{BOUG} &: \text{Menge aller beliebig oft unterbrechbaren Ger{\"a}te}\\
J_{BOUHG} &: \text{Menge aller beliebig oft unterbrechbaren Ger{\"a}te}\\
J_{EVG} &: \text{Menge aller einmalig verschiebaren Ger{\"a}te}\\
J_{EVHG} &: \text{Menge aller einmalig verschiebaren hybriden Ger{\"a}te}\\
J_{MUG}&: \text{Menge aller mehrmalig unterbrechbaren Ger{\"a}te}\\
J_{MUHG} &: \text{Menge aller mehrmalig unterbrechbaren hybriden Ger{\"a}te}\\
l &: \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
Bezeichnung f{\"u}r die aktuelle Phase des Programms von Ger{\"a}t $j$ bei \\
unterbrechbaren Ger{\"a}ten\end{tabular} \\ 
L_{el} (t) &: \text{Lastgrenze f{\"u}r die elektrische Leistung zum Zeitpunkt $t$}\\
n &: \text{Gesamtzahl der Phasen des Programms von Ger{\"a}t $j$ bei unterbrechbaren Ger{\"a}ten} \\ 
p_{el} (t) &: \text{Preis für den vom Stromanbieter bezogenen Strom zum Zeitpunkt $t$} \\
p_{EZ,i} (t) &: \text{Preis für den von Erzeuger $i$ in das Netz eingespeisten Strom} \\
p_{Gas} (t) &: \text{Preis für das vom Gasanbieter bezogene Gas zum Zeitpunkt $t$} \\
p_j &: \text{Dauer des Programms von Ger{\"a}t $j$}\\ 
p_{j,i} &: \text{Dauer der Phase i des Programms von Ger{\"a}t $j$ bei unterbrechbaren Ger{\"a}ten}\\
p_{j,min} &: \text{Mindestlaufzeit des Ger{\"a}tes $j$ wenn es in Betrieb ist }\\
p_{j,non} &: \text{Mindestruhezeit des Ger{\"a}tes $j$ wenn es nicht in Betrieb ist}\\
P^{Beob}(t) &: \text{beobachtbare, aber nicht beinflussbarer Gesamtverbrauch zum Zeitpunkt $t$}\\
P^{BOUG}_j(t) &: \text{elektrischer Verbrauch des beliebig oft unterbrechbaren Ger{\"a}tes $j$ zum Zeitpunkt $t$}\\
P^{BOUHG}_j(t) &: \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
elektrischer Verbrauch des beliebig of unterbrechbaren hybriden Ger{\"a}tes $j$ \\
zum Zeitpunkt t \end{tabular} \\ 
P^{EVG}_j(t) &: \text{elektrischer Verbrauch des einmalig verschiebaren Ger{\"a}tes $j$ zum Zeitpunkt $t$}\\
P^{EVHG}_j(t) &: \text{elektrischer Verbrauch des einmalig verschiebaren hybriden Ger{\"a}tes $j$ zum Zeitpunkt $t$}\\
P_{EZ,i} (t) &: \text{vom Erzeuger i erbrachte elektrische Leistung zum Zeitpunkt $t$}\\
P_{EZ,ges} (t) &: \text{gesamte elektrisch erzeugte Leistung zum Zeitpunkt $t$}\\
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
P^{Grund}(t) &: \text{Grundlast zum Zeitpunkt $t$}\\
P^{MUG}_j(t) &: \text{elektrischer Verbrauch des mehrmalig unterbrechbaren Ger{\"a}tes $j$ zum Zeitpunkt $t$}\\
P^{MUHG}_j(t) &: \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
elektrischer Verbrauch des mehrmalig unterbrechbaren hybriden Ger{\"a}tes $j$ \\
 zum Zeitpunkt t \end{tabular} \\ 
P_U  (t) &: \text{elektrische {\"U}berschussleistung zum Zeitpunkt $t$}\\
P_{V,ges} (t) &: \text{elektrischer Gesamtverbrauch zum Zeitpunkt $t$}\\
Q_{j,l} (t_r) &: \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
Leistung der Phase $l$ des Programms von Ger{\"a}t $j$ bei unterbrechbaren Ger{\"a}ten \\
zur Zeit $t_r$ \end{tabular} \\ 
Q_{j,Run}&: \text{Leistung des Ger{\"a}tes $j$ wenn es in Betrieb ist}\\
Q_{j,Standby}&: \text{Standbyleistung des Ger{\"a}tes $j$} \\ 
Q_j(t_r) &: \text{Leistung des Ger{\"a}tes j relativ zum Startzeitpunkt}\\ 
r_j &: \text{Release-Zeitpunkt des Ger{\"a}tes $j$} \\
 s_j &: \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
Relativer Startzeitpunkt des Ger{\"a}tes $j$.\\
Angegeben in Bezug auf den fr{\"u}hestm{\"o}glichen Startzeitpunkt\end{tabular} \\ 
 s_{j,i} &: \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
Relativer Startzeitpunkt der Phase i des Programms von Ger{\"a}t $j$ bei \\
unterbrechbaren Ger{\"a}ten. Angegeben in Bezug auf den fr{\"u}hestm{\"o}glichen Startzeitpunkt\end{tabular} \\
t &: \text{absolute Systemzeit} \\ 
t_r &: \text{relative Zeit in Bezug auf den Startzeitpunkt des Ger{\"a}tes $j$ } \\ 
tDoF_j &: \text{temporal Degree of Freedom des Ger{\"a}tes $j$}\\ 
T_{WS} (t) &: \text{Wassertemperatur des Warmwasserspeicher zum Zeitpunkt $t$}\\
T_{WS}^{max} &: \text{technisch maximal zul{\"a}ssige Wassertemperatur des Warmwasserspeicher}\\
T_{WS}^{min} &: \text{technisch minimal zul{\"a}ssige Wassertemperatur des Warmwasserspeicher}\\
W(t) &: \text{Warmwassernutzung zum Zeitpunkt $t$}\\
\end{align*}



\end{document}
```

The problem is that the first page is empty and I do not know the reason for that. I simply want to have all explanation for the variables beginn at the same position for every page. This is why I use an aligne environment.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You are planning to make a list of symbols etc. There are packages for this, `nomencl` or `glossaries`. They might be better suited than using `align*`

Comment: Put `\allowdisplaybreaks` in the preamble.

Comment: This should be *not* done with `align*` to begin with.

Answer (score 5):

Your `align` structure is too large to fit on a single page. I suggest you insert the instruction `\allowdisplaybreaks` immediately prior to `\begin{align}`.

---

*Addendum*: Using an `align*` environment to construct this table is grossly inefficient as well as needlessly tedious. You may want to familiarize yourself with (a) the `longtable` environment, which allows page breaks, and (b) the `p` column type, which sets its contents using line breaks automatically, as needed.

The following code illustrates how to render the first few rows of the full table using a `longtable` environment. Note that the first column is set automatically in math mode, and that the second is of type `p`, with a width of 12 centimeters; adjust the width to suit your preferences.

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array,longtable,ragged2e}
\usepackage[fixamsmath,disallowspaces]{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\underline{Verwendete Bezeichnungen}

\begin{longtable}{ >{$}r<{$}  >{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{12cm} }
\sigma_{Ab}  & Koeffizient für die Berechnung der Temperaturabnahme des Warmwasserspeichers durch den Verbrauch von Warmwasser  \\
\sigma_{Ver} &  Temperaturverlust des Warmwasserspeichers  \\
\sigma_ {Zu} & Koeffizient für die Berechnung der Temperaturzunahme des Warmwasserspeichers durch das Verbrennen von Gas \\
d_j          & spätestmöglicher Zeitpunkt an dem das Programm von Gerät~$j$ beendet sein muss\\
g_{j,Run,l}^{a} (t_r) & Gasverbrauch des Gerätes~$j$ in der Phase $l$ unter Verwendung von Profil~$a$. Gasverbrauch ist relativ zum Startzeitpunkt angegeben \\
G_{Ges}(t)   & gesamter Gasverbrauch aller Gasverbraucher in Bezug auf die Systemzeit $t$\\
G^{GV}_j(t)  & Gasverbrauch des Gerätes $j$ in Bezug auf die Systemzeit $t$ \\
J_{BOUG}     & Menge aller beliebig oft unterbrechbaren Geräte\\
J_{BOUHG}    & Menge aller beliebig oft unterbrechbaren hybriden Geräte\\
J_{EVG}      & Menge aller einmalig verschiebaren Geräte\\
J_{EVHG}     & Menge aller einmalig verschiebaren hybriden Geräte\\
J_{MUG}      & Menge aller mehrmalig unterbrechbaren Geräte\\
J_{MUHG}     & Menge aller mehrmalig unterbrechbaren hybriden Geräte\\
\vdots & $\vdots$\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast help. I used \allowdisplaybreaks and now it looks very good :-)